# Mocha testing: Why am I getting null as the user?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, mongoose-schema

So I have put this testing suite. Unfortunately, I did not have the foresight to test that the user I got back from the database was joe and I did not because I already have a test here for saving 'joe', the user:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../src/user');

describe('Creating records', () => {
  it('saves a user', done => {
    const joe = new User({ name: 'Joe' });

    joe.save().then(() => {
      // Has joe been saved successfully
      assert(!joe.isNew);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

And it is passing. I went on to create these tests:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../src/user');
const Comment = require('../src/comment');
const BlogPost = require('../src/blogPost');

describe('Association', () => {
  let joe, blogPost, comment;
  beforeEach(done => {
    joe = new User({ name: 'Joe' });
    blogPost = new BlogPost({
      title: 'Eloquent JavaScript',
      content: 'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
    });
    comment = new Comment({ content: 'Love this post' });
    joe.blogPosts.push(blogPost);
    blogPost.comments.push(comment);
    comment.user = joe;

    Promise.all([joe.save(), blogPost.save(), comment.save()]).then(() =>
      done()
    );
  });

  it('saves a relation between a user and a blogpost', done => {
    User.findOne({ name: 'Joe' })
      .populate('blogPosts')
      .then(user => {
        assert(user.blogPosts[0].title === 'Eloquent JavaScript');
        done();
      });
  });
```

And they are passing, but when I added this test here:

```
xit('saves a full relation graph', () => {
    User.findOne({ name: 'Joe' })
      .populate({
        path: 'blogPosts',
        populate: {
          path: 'comments',
          model: 'comment',
          populate: {
            path: 'user',
            model: 'user'
          }
        }
      })
      .then(user => {
        assert(user.name === 'Joe');
        assert(user.blogPosts[0].title === 'Eloquent JavaScript');
        assert(
          user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].content ===
            'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
        );
        assert(user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].user.name === 'Joe');
        done();
      });
  });
```

It fails. I console logged it and found that for user I am getting back `null` and I am unclear as to why I am getting back null. So this was the output in my terminal:

```
{ _id: 5bb92e5fe6b40e97e21cd95f,
  user: null,
  content: 'Love this post',
  __v: 0 }
```

when I checked in on the success of this test by console logging like so:

```
it('saves a full relation graph', () => {
    User.findOne({ name: 'Joe' })
      .populate({
        path: 'blogPosts',
        populate: {
          path: 'comments',
          model: 'comment',
          populate: {
            path: 'user',
            model: 'user'
          }
        }
      })
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user.blogPosts[0].comments[0]);
        done();
      });
  });
```

Can anyone see why I am getting `user: null` instead of 'Joe'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to utilize [**exec()**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) after your [**populate**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to get an actual promise:

```
xit('saves a full relation graph', () => {
    User.findOne({ name: 'Joe' })
      .populate({
        path: 'blogPosts',
        populate: {
          path: 'comments',
          model: 'comment',
          populate: {
            path: 'user',
            model: 'user'
          }
        }
      }).exec()
      .then(user => {
        assert(user.name === 'Joe');
        assert(user.blogPosts[0].title === 'Eloquent JavaScript');
        assert(
          user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].content ===
            'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
        );
        assert(user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].user.name === 'Joe');
        done();
      });
  });
```